# Why I change kafka min.insync.replicas error?

Tags: apache-kafka, interrupt

When I change min.insync.replicas,I found that the __consumer_offsets's min.insync.replicas is not change.I want to confirm, if I change this configuration, will the isr on the original topic be changed automatically, or do I need to do something manually?